# How to covert the address from KCOV output to filename:lineno using addr2line?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, addr2line

I want to use `KCOV` (code coverage for fuzzing) in the Linux kernel to record the coverage of certain system calls.  I have enabled the corresponding kernel configs started with the code example in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dev-tools/kcov.rst):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

#define KCOV_INIT_TRACE         _IOR('c', 1, unsigned long)
#define KCOV_ENABLE         _IO('c', 100)
#define KCOV_DISABLE            _IO('c', 101)
#define COVER_SIZE          (64<<10)

#define KCOV_TRACE_PC  0
#define KCOV_TRACE_CMP 1

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;
    unsigned long *cover, n, i;

    /* A single fd descriptor allows coverage collection on a single
        * thread.
        */
    fd = open("/sys/kernel/debug/kcov", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
        perror("open"), exit(1);
    /* Setup trace mode and trace size. */
    if (ioctl(fd, KCOV_INIT_TRACE, COVER_SIZE))
        perror("ioctl"), exit(1);
    /* Mmap buffer shared between kernel- and user-space. */
    cover = (unsigned long*)mmap(NULL, COVER_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned long),
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if ((void*)cover == MAP_FAILED)
        perror("mmap"), exit(1);
    /* Enable coverage collection on the current thread. */
    if (ioctl(fd, KCOV_ENABLE, KCOV_TRACE_PC))
        perror("ioctl"), exit(1);
    /* Reset coverage from the tail of the ioctl() call. */
    __atomic_store_n(&cover[0], 0, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    /* That's the target syscal call. */
    read(-1, NULL, 0);
    /* Read number of PCs collected. */
    n = __atomic_load_n(&cover[0], __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("0x%lx\n", cover[i + 1]);
    /* Disable coverage collection for the current thread. After this call
        * coverage can be enabled for a different thread.
        */
    if (ioctl(fd, KCOV_DISABLE, 0))
        perror("ioctl"), exit(1);
    /* Free resources. */
    if (munmap(cover, COVER_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned long)))
        perror("munmap"), exit(1);
    if (close(fd))
        perror("close"), exit(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The doc said `After piping through addr2line output of the program looks as follows::` but I cannot get the same results.

I compiled it with `gcc -g`, and it would print the addresses if I ran the executable.  Then I tried to use `addr2line` by `addr2line -e a.out ${one_of_the_output_addresses}`, it always returned `??:0`.  I searched some materials and some said I need to subtract the base VA to obtain the offset as the `addr2line` argument, but the program finishes immediately so I cannot get the value from `/proc/<PID>/maps`.  I also tried to add a `sleep` function to the end to ensure I can get the base VA, but it still outputs `??:0` if I specify `VA - base VA` for `addr2line`.  Any idea to reproduce the `filename:lineno` output from `KCOV` doc?

Comment: Try [disabling ASLR](https://askubuntu.com/a/318476/1020452) when collecting Kcov data.

Comment: @yugr Thank you for the advice. I tried disabling ASLR.  Do I need to provide `offset` (or the output VA?) as the argument to `addr2line`?

Comment: No, I believe it's enough to pass addresses reported by Kcov.